# What's the diff between router isActive and router.isNavigating in Durandal

Tags: durandal

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html says

> Note that each navigable route in the model has an `isActive` flag which
>   will be true when the associated route is active. The final thing to
>   notice is that we have bound a simple spinner animation to the
>   `router.isNavigating`.

First, could someone please help me to clarify what's the diff between isActive and isNavigating?

Second, isActive refers to the code below

```
<ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
    <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I searched the official code hosted [here](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/platforms/HTML/Samples/css/samples.css) but I failed to locate where active class is defined. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.isNavigating` is true if the router is currently transitioning from one route to another.

`isActive` will be true for a route if that route is currently begin displayed.

Say you have two routes in your navigation model:

```
 var routes = [
                { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'Home' },
                { route: 'subpage', moduleId: 'subpage', title: 'Sub Page' }
              ]
```

You start off viewing the home route, so home has `isActive` true.
`router.isNavigating` is false as you're not transitioning.

Then you click a link to take you to `subpage`

home `isActive` is now false, subpage `isActive` is true and `isNavigating` becomes true while durandal loads the view and viewmodel and performs the transition.

Once it's finished loading `isNavigating` becomes false. Home is not active, subpage still is.

You can't find the `.active` class because it's not in the durandal css. It's in bootstrap.css

Comment: Using isActive you can set one menu item a different color to indicate the currently selected view.  In your example, a css style (active) is applied only to the li of the current route.  Using isNavigating you can show an animated graphic when view transition occurs to let the user know something is happening.  Same thing, set some css to an animated gif and bind the css style to the isNavigating property, default the visibility to hidden and show it when isNavigating is true.

Comment: I can find  isNavigating's official documentation from  http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#class/Router/property/isNavigating, but where is isActive's official documentation?Except mentioned at http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html